# NodeJS pg module doesn't rollback inside a transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres, node-pg-pool

When I try to rollback inside a transaction:

```
const client = await pool.connect()
try {
    await client.query('BEGIN')
    const result = await client.query('SELECT...')
    if (result) { await client.query('ROLLBACK') } //DOESN'T WORK
    if (result) { throw new Error() }//WORKS. WHY?
    (...)
    await client.query('COMMIT')
}
catch (e) {
    await client.query('ROLLBACK')
}
finally {
    client.release()
}
```

Why rollback only works when thrown an exception?

Comment: I just wrote it wrong here

Comment: Can you describe the malfunction in detail?

Comment: The rollback is done only if I thrown an exception. Sending a query with 'rollback' has no effect. Throwing an exception solves my problem, but I just wanted to know why sendind client.query('rollback') has no effect.  
It seems that rollback only works inside the block 'catch'

Comment: What do you mean by "has no effect"? What is the code in "*`(...)`*" doing?